Spring Boot, controller and my securityConfig files are never used
my name is Andre. I created a Spring Boot Web Application Project and my problem is that  both my controller and my securityConfig files are never used (IntelliJ tells me so). I am using Spring Boot 3.3 on Windows 11. Google tells me to place my main app file in the base package and to have my controllers in sub packages below the base package but this does not work. I am already using
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

in the pom.xml file.
When I run my application, the index.html comes up just fine (note: I am using traditional HTML files and NOT thymeleaf). My login form is on this index.html page. I enter the proper credentials and the browser displays a mixture of the home.html page and the error.html page. My Ajax file tries to run but fails to find an endpoint called "loggInUser" because the method "patty" used to call the  loggInUser() method never gets called because the class UserController is never used according to IntelliJ.

How do I link my zipped Project so others can see it? Thanks

My advice to build the skeleton of your Spring projects is to always use https://start.spring.io/. For example, here I am shared the configuration of a project that includes Spring Web + Spring Security https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.3.0&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=21&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web,security.

Once said, your issue may be that you are not annotating your classes as @Controller (your web controller) or @Configuration (your security configuration). For that case you could either share your project in github or paste the code (formatted) in your question.

GitHub Repository for Practice Project is andre1011green/practiceProject

After looking to your source code available, I see your class DataController is not annotated with @RestController or @Controller and that is why Spring cannot map all the endpoints included in that class (including @GetMapping("/loggInUser")).
Besides that, I would recommend you to look at best practices when autowiring in Spring. Ideally you do autowiring always in the constructor instead of on private fields, as it makes your code more testable.

I did as you said and annotated my other controller classes with @Controller, IntelliJ still says my controllers are never used BUT I DO SEE from my console output that my controllers are being used because the System.out.println() in my controllers are now being executed.
I will check the best practices for Auto wiring you gave me, thanks silver_mx, I am getting a little closer
